# Placing content side-by-side: minipage-columns cannot break pages and paracol-columns introduce suprious horizontal space

Tags: minipage, paracol, parcolumns

I would like to put items side-by-side in a two-column layout with some space
in-between (think of three columns with the middle one being empty). I would
like to define an environment which I pass the content of the left and right
column for each entry. So far I used side-by-side `minipage`s (see 'Version 1'
below) which works well but fails with longer entries (see below, where there
is a lot of vertical space left on the first page as the second entry is
moved to page 2). I then found `paracol`. I again defined an environment
(see 'Version 2' below), but as you can see (on page 3 and 4 of the resulting
PDF), there is some horizontal space introduced (why?). The entries in
the left column are not perfectly right-aligned anymore and the entries
in the right column are not perfectly left-aligned anymore. How can
this be fixed?

(If there is a better solution to the problem (without paracol), I'd also be
interested to know, as I had issues with using footnotes with `paracol`
even when using the package's functionality for that. What I need is
essentially full functionality within the columns (as I also print
references there and other things). Also, necessarily, the columns have different widths in my case (which rules out `multicol` I believe) and can extend over pages)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Misc
\parindent0mm% to see better what's going on
\parskip1ex% define paragraph skip

% Define fractions of \textwidth for the columns (fractions are more suitable for \columnratio below)
\newcommand{\lcol}{0.24}% fraction of the left column
\newcommand{\mcol}{0.04}% horizontal space between the two columns
\newcommand{\rcol}{0.72}% fraction of the right column

% Bar for section headings (to see better what's going on)
\newcommand*{\sectionbar}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tikz\fill(0mm,0ex)rectangle+(\lcol\textwidth,0.5ex);}}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily}{\sectionbar}{\mcol\textwidth}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{1.4ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}

% Version 1: minipage approach (works well but fails over pagebreaks)

\newcommand*{\entrymini}[2]{% arguments = (left entry, right entry)
  \par
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\lcol\textwidth}%
    {\raggedleft #1\par}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\rcol\textwidth}%
    #2%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par
}

% Version 2: paracol approach (introduces spurious space in the middle)

% Define an environment for switching to the 3-column layout
\newcommand*{\entrypara}[2]{% arguments = (left entry, right entry)
  \columnratio{\lcol,\mcol,\rcol}
  \begin{paracol}{3}
    {\raggedleft #1\par}%
    \switchcolumn%
    \switchcolumn%
    #2%
  \end{paracol}
}

\begin{document}
This is the solution with minipages, which works for many entries except if there are page breaks:

\section{With minipages}
\entrymini{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrymini{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}

\clearpage\bigskip
This is the solution with paracol (which neither aligns the left column properly
on the right, nor aligns the right column properly on the left; where is the additional
horizontal space coming from?):

\section{With paracol}
\entrypara{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrypara{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
\end{document}
```

**Update (with various solutions)**

The following incorporates a solution with `paracol` as pointed out by Pieter in the comments under this post. It also incorporates two approaches with lists (but none breaks lines correctly for longer items) as pointed out by Pieter and Ulrike.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Misc
\parindent0mm% to see better what's going on
\parskip1ex% define paragraph skip

% Define fractions of \textwidth for the columns (fractions are more suitable for \columnratio below)
\newcommand{\lcol}{0.24}% fraction of the left column
\newcommand{\mcol}{0.04}% horizontal space between the two columns
\newcommand{\rcol}{0.72}% fraction of the right column

% Bar for section headings (to see better what's going on)
\newcommand*{\sectionbar}{\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tikz\fill(0mm,0ex)rectangle+(\lcol\textwidth,0.5ex);}}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sffamily}{\sectionbar}{\mcol\textwidth}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{1.4ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0ex plus .2ex}

% Version 1: minipage approach (works well but fails over pagebreaks)
\newcommand*{\entrymini}[2]{% arguments = (left entry, right entry)
  \par
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\lcol\textwidth}%
    {\raggedleft #1\par}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\rcol\textwidth}%
    #2%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par
}

% Version 2: paracol approach
\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}% => fixes space-problem
\newcommand*{\entrypara}[2]{% arguments = (left entry, right entry)
  \columnratio{\lcol,\mcol,\rcol}
  \begin{paracol}{3}
    {\raggedleft #1\par}%
    \switchcolumn%
    \switchcolumn%
    #2%
  \end{paracol}
}

% Version 3: With lists (as suggested by Pieter and Ulrike)
\newcommand*{\entrylist}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\mcol\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\lcol\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    }%
  \item[#1]#2\end{list}
}

% Version 4: With enumitem
\newcommand*{\entryitem}[2]{
  \begin{itemize}[align=right, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=\lcol\textwidth, labelsep=\mcol\textwidth]
    \item[#1] #2
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}
\section{With minipages}
\entrymini{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrymini{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
\entrymini{Here is some longer text that should break over lines and be right-aligned}{\blindtext[1]}
\clearpage

\section{With paracol}
\entrypara{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrypara{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
\entrypara{Here is some longer text that should break over lines and be right-aligned}{\blindtext[1]}
\clearpage

\section{With lists}
\entrylist{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrylist{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
\entrylist{Here is some longer text that should break over lines and be right-aligned}{\blindtext[1]}
\clearpage

\section{With enumitem}
\entryitem{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entryitem{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
\entryitem{Here is some longer text that should break over lines and be right-aligned}{\blindtext[1]}
\entryitem{Here is a hack}{}
\entryitem{... not very elegant but works}{\vspace{-2mm}}
\entryitem{}{\vspace{-13mm}\blindtext[1]}
\entryitem{{\smash{\parbox[t]{\lcol\textwidth}{\raggedleft Here is some longer text that should break over lines and be right-aligned}}}}{\blindtext[1]}% here is a nicer version for longer labels -- but Pieter's solution (see the accepted solution) is even more elegant in this regard.
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: The extra space with `paracol` is two times the `\columnsep`. With `\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}` it disappears. But then you could also use just two columns and let `\columnsep` do the empty middle column.

Comment: If your left column is always as simple as in this example (one line), then this could be done with a `list` environment.

Comment: thanks a lot, Pieter, excellent. Interestingly, the two-column idea with `\columnsep` move everything to the right, but the `\setlength{\columnsep}{0pt}` approached worked great.

Comment: The footnotes in `paracol` can be done with `\footnotelayout{m}` .

Comment: That I know, but in my not-so-minimal example, it put the footnote not on the same page but one page later. Couldn't reproduce it in the minimal working example above and thus omitted it.

Comment: The column width ratios in `paracol` are applied to the width after the `\columnsep` have been subtracted, so it is not that fraction of `\textwidth`.

Comment: I can imagine that larger footnotes move to the next page. I have studies `paracol`'s page breaking algorithm and I was wondering how they could get the page-wide footnotes right. So it seems they couldn't.

Comment: your example clearly looks like a description list. So why don't you use it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ulrike, my update now incorporates such ideas based on `list` (thanks to Pieter) and `enumitem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `list` environment that I suggested in my second comment. **EDIT:** allow for multiline left column. However there won't be a page break in that entry.

```
\newcommand*{\entrylist}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\mcol\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\lcol\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    }%
  \item[{\parbox[t][\baselineskip]{\labelwidth}{\raggedleft#1}}]#2\end{list}
}

\section{With list}
\entrylist{April 01, 2021}{\blindtext[1]}
\entrylist{April 29, 2021}{\blindtext[3]}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this would be perfect if there was a way to have the item label break over lines if it's too long (and still be right-aligned). I have a list version based on `enumitem` which behaves slightly differently from yours (I update my example soon) but none can have items that break over lines.

Comment: I incorporated this idea and one based on `enumitem` in my posted update. If you have a solution for longer labels, that would be great.

Comment: One 'hack' (see update, last example) is to define two entries with only the first argument for labels with 2 lines, and then a third entry with only the second entry, suitably shifted vertically. Quite a bad hack, though.

Comment: Allowing for a multi-line label is easy using `\parbox`, but then there will not be a page break inside that label if the entry crosses a page boundary. Page breaking in both the label and the righthandside entry requires ingenious solutions like `paracol`.

Comment: Thanks, my update contains this version now (last line). I used `[t]` to vertically align the content of the `parbox` correctly and `\raggedleft` for the horizontal alignment. Then I needed to suppress the vertical space the longer item creates, which I now did with `\smash` (there might be more elegant solution for this step), but that works for now.

Comment: See the update in my solution.

Comment: ... that's great, thanks Pieter.